# Finding the derivative of $\sin(x)/x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Prove this function is differentiable and find it's derivative.
$$
S(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\sin x}{x} & x\neq0\\
1              & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
The derivative in $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is : $\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}$, but I don't know how to find the derivative at $x=0$

Comment: Just use the definition of the derivative in one point… what's the definition for a function to be differentiable in an arbitrary $x_0$? Then set $x_0 = 0$. Where are you stuck?

Comment: $\lim _{h\to 0} \frac{S(h)-S(0)}{h}$

Comment: Yes, what is is $S(h)$, what is $S(0)$? Where are you stuck in calculating this limit?

Comment: @Gono I get to $\lim_{h\to 0}(\sin h  - h)/h^2$ and I don't know where to go next.

Comment: Now try using L Hopital to evaluate the limit...

Comment: @Wrench Yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x}-1}{x} = \frac{\sin x -x}{x^2}=
\frac{3\sin \frac{x}{3}-4 \sin^3 \frac{x}{3}-x}{x^2} \sim \frac{3\sin \frac{x}{3}-x}{x^2}=3\frac{\sin \frac{x}{3}-\frac{x}{3}}{x^2}$$
Second and last member without $3$ have same limits. Can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you might do something like this

$$
f’(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}\\
f’(0)= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{\sin h }{h} -1}{h} $$

and then use L’Hospitals rule to evaluate the limit. But what you forget is that the given function is discontinuous at zero and hence derivative will not exist at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $S$ is even, its derivative at $x=0$ is either $0$ or undefined. There are many ways to show the former holds here, e.g.$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-1}{x}+\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^2}=0+0=0.$$Indeed$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}=-\frac12,\,\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}=\frac16$$are famous results which, multiplied by $\lim_{x\to0}x=0$, gives what we need.